# Document Types error after updating to Umbraco 7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I updated my Umbraco version from 7.1 to the new 7.2.
I didn't got any errors during the update but now that I'm running through my websites I've notice there's an issue with my document types (node.types)
When I try to see my documents types list I got the following error:

> Received an error from the server Failed to retrieve data for child
>   nodes undefined
>
> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Tuple.Tuple(bool?, int?)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> EXCEPTION DETAILS:
>
> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best
>   overloaded method match for 'System.Tuple.Tuple(bool?,
>   int?)' has some invalid arguments STACKTRACE:
>
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    at CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Type , Object , Object )    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeBaseRepository`1.ContentTypeQueryMapper.<MapContentTypes>b__d6(Object
>   x)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeBaseRepository`1.ContentTypeQueryMapper.MapContentTypes(Int32[]
>   contentTypeIds, Database db, IDictionary`2& associatedTemplates,
>   IDictionary`2& parentContentTypeIds)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeBaseRepository`1.ContentTypeQueryMapper.GetContentTypes[TRepo](Int32[]
>   contentTypeIds, Database db, TRepo contentTypeRepository,
>   ITemplateRepository templateRepository)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeRepository.PerformGetAll(Int32[]
>   ids)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`2.GetAll(TId[]
>   ids)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeRepository.PerformGetByQuery(IQuery`1
>   query)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`2.GetByQuery(IQuery`1
>   query)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentTypeService.GetContentTypeChildren(Int32
>   id)    at umbraco.loadNodeTypes.Render(XmlTree& tree)    at
>   Umbraco.Web.Trees.ApplicationTreeExtensions.TryGetXmlTree(ApplicationTree
>   appTree, String id, FormDataCollection formCollection)    at
>   Umbraco.Web.Trees.ApplicationTreeExtensions.TryLoadFromLegacyTree(ApplicationTree
>   appTree, String id, FormDataCollection formCollection, UrlHelper
>   urlHelper, String currentSection)    at
>   Umbraco.Web.Trees.LegacyTreeController.GetTreeNodes(String id,
>   FormDataCollection queryStrings)    at
>   Umbraco.Web.Trees.TreeControllerBase.GetNodes(String id,
>   FormDataCollection queryStrings)    at lambda_method(Closure , Object
>   , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__c(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Anyone know why would this happens, or had the same issue after updating Umbraco? I also get an error when trying to create new document types.

Update:

This is the error I get when I try to create a new document type:

> Server Error in '/Umbracast' Application.
>
> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Tuple.Tuple(bool?, int?)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best
>   overloaded method match for 'System.Tuple.Tuple(bool?,
>   int?)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Tuple.Tuple(bool?, int?)' has some invalid
>   arguments]    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object ,
>   Object ) +344
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) +368    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite ,
>   Type , Object , Object ) +261
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeQueryMapper.b__d6(Object
>   x) +1379    System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +244
>
>   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +196
>   System.Linq.d__81`1.MoveNext() +472
>
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +488
>
>   System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() +252
>
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +488
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +103
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeQueryMapper.MapContentTypes(Int32[]
>   contentTypeIds, Database db, IDictionary`2& associatedTemplates,
>   IDictionary`2& parentContentTypeIds) +1908
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeQueryMapper.GetContentTypes(Int32[]
>   contentTypeIds, Database db, TRepo contentTypeRepository,
>   ITemplateRepository templateRepository) +103
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.ContentTypeRepository.PerformGetAll(Int32[]
>   ids) +761
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`2.GetAll(TId[]
>   ids) +1666
>   Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentTypeService.GetAllContentTypes(Int32[]
>   ids) +107    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.DocumentType.GetAllAsList()
>   +79    umbraco.cms.presentation.create.controls.nodeType.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +617    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Comment: Can you run your internal indexer (from the developer tab)?

Comment: I cannot get InternalIndexer Examine index to finish rebuilding actually.

Comment: I think it something with latest data change (update and save ) to the db. because I had the exact case. So I replace the DB to a backup DB without latest changes, and than the exception gone and I can build My indexes.
If you find another solution I be glad to know also.